# mysql query result to string returns nil

Tags: php, mysql

Trying to retrieve some information from mysql query and print that in a string, but couldnt understand the issue, according to here http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-result.php it should be correct but it returns empty.

```
$sql = new mysqli('xxxx', 'xxxx', 'xxxxxx', 'xxxxx');
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
        printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
exit;
}
echo " user id  ", $user_id, "\n";
echo "event id ", $event_id, "\n";
$query ="SELECT A1.event_name,A1.start_date,A2.first_name,A2.last_name  FROM OWN_EVENTS A1 INNER JOIN  USERS A2 ON  A1.event_id  =  $event_id WHERE  A2.user_id=A1.user_id ";
$result = $sql->query($query);    
if (!$result) {
    sendResponse(417, json_encode("Query failed"));
exit;
}
$row = mysql_fetch_row($result);
echo "row[2] ", $row[2], "\n";
echo "row[3] ", $row[3], "\n";
//echo "result",$result,"\n";

$querySend ="SELECT email FROM USERS WHERE user_id = $user_id";
$resultSend = $sql->query($querySend);    
if (!resultSend) {
    sendResponse(417, json_encode("Query failed"));
exit;
}
$rowSend = mysql_fetch_row($resultSend);
echo "rowSend[0] ", $rowSend[0], "\n";
echo $rowSend["email"];
```

LOG:

```
user id  8
event id 95

Warning: mysql_fetch_row() expects parameter 1 to be resource, object given in /var/insertToNotifications.php on line 180
row[2] 
row[3] 

Notice: Use of undefined constant resultSend - assumed 'resultSend' in /var/insertToNotifications.php on line 187

Warning: mysql_fetch_row() expects parameter 1 to be resource, object given in /var/insertToNotifications.php on line 191
rowSend[0]
```

results in phpmyadmin:

[image]

[image]

My goal is to able to print something like `$body = "Hi,\n\n $row[2],$row[3]  has invited you to $row[0] starting  $row[1] \n\n \n\n ";`

How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are mixing mysqli_* functions with the deprecated mysql_* functions. You want to continue with the mysqli functions to get your result like so:

```
$query ="SELECT A1.event_name,A1.start_date,A2.first_name,A2.last_name  FROM OWN_EVENTS A1 INNER JOIN  USERS A2 ON  A1.event_id  =  $event_id WHERE  A2.user_id=A1.user_id ";
$result = $sql->query($query);    
if (!$result) {
    sendResponse(417, json_encode("Query failed"));
exit;
}
$row = $result->fetch_row($result);
```

Here is the doc on the methods you can call on the `$result` object: http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.mysqli-result.php

Comment: thanks for the answer, already followed the link, must have missed `i` part

Answer (score 1):

You're mixing mysqli (note the `i`) and mysql (note the **LACK** of an `i`). The two libraries are **NOT** interoperable, and handles/results from one mean absolutely NOTHING to the other.

You probably want

```
$row = mysqli_fetch_row($result);
            ^----
```

and should probably not be mixing the procedural and OOP versions of the library anyways. Pick one style and stick with it.